# Xml Parse with DOM API

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom

I use this method to parse XML file in an android app

```
private Document parseXmlFile(String file) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        Document dom;
        dom = null;
        try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom = db.parse("data.xml");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) 
          catch (SAXException se) 
          catch (IOException ioe) 
    }
    return dom;
}
```

and this is the XML file that i try to parse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<coloritems>
   <colory>
       <id>#55dd23</id>
       <name>blue</name>
       <category>blue</category>
   </colory>
   <colory>
       <id>#55ded3</id>
       <name>blue</name>
       <category>blue</category>
   </colory>
</coloritems>
```

but the method return a null object , I think that is the path of the file , how I fix it if tha'ts the problem ? and where do I have  put the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The db.parse method takes an inputstream
So you need to open your file and pass inputstream to it and not just the fle name